# What prepositions to use in a sentence with "Know where I stand..."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, questions

I created a rating chart to be used as a reference in my reviews. In the chart's description, I want to say "This rating chart is for the readers to know where I stand ____ the video game."

I know the "on" preposition can be used when telling my opinion on an issue, debate, or these sorts of things. Does the same apply to this case or what other preposition should write down?

Comment: You might use *as to* or *on* or *about*.  It is explained nicely here - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76733/how-do-i-choose-between-as-to-on-of-and-about  It would suggest you use *on*.  I would agree.

Comment: What @EllieK said. You might *also* use ***with, regarding, apropos, concerning,...*** There are a lot of options here, and no single term is ***the*** "correct" solution.

Comment: Yes, it proved to be helpful in some sort